# Google Cloud SQL Driver replacement

Tags: mysql, driver, google-cloud-sql

I was reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external) from Google Cloud SQL and it recommends that I have to use the MySQL original driver to connect to Google Cloud SQL from a external application.

I am currently using the cloud_sql.jar driver (old driver) for a external application.

Do you think I have to replace the cloud_sql.jar driver to the original driver ([Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/))

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please stop using the old driver and switch to Connector/J. Note that you will need to request and IP for the Cloud SQL instance and add the network you are connecting from to the list of authorized networks.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess